# stream.CopyTo - file empty. asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I'm saving an uploaded image using this code:

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create(savePath))
{
   stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

When the image is saved to its destination folder, it's empty, 0 kb. What could possible be wrong here? I've checked the stream.Length before copying and its not empty.

Comment: Can we see your code where you load the original stream please? Also, try inserting the line stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); just before your copy to to make sure you are at the beginning of the original stream.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The fact you say "I've checked the stream.Length before copying and its not empty" makes me wonder about the *stream position* before copying.

If you've already consumed the source stream once then although the stream isn't zero length, its position may be at the end of the stream - so there is nothing left to copy.

If the stream is seekable (which it will be for a `MemoryStream` or a `FileStream` and many others), try putting

```
stream.Position = 0
```

just before the copy. This resets the stream position to the beginning, meaning the whole stream will be copied by your code.

Comment: You learn something new everyday! Indeed it was. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to put the following before `CopyTo()`

```
fileStream.Position = 0
```

Make sure to use the `Flush()` after this, to avoid empty file after copy.

```
fileStream.Flush()
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem started for me after migrating my project from to .NET Core 1 to 2.2.

I fixed this issue by setting the `Position` of my filestream to zero.

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    fileStream.Position = 0;
    await imageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```