# File saving as 0 KB when using HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream.CopyToAsync(FileStream)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-5.0

I want to save my file in disk. I have,

```
public async Task SaveFileContentsAsync(string filePath, Stream stream)
{
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);// await in using is required
        }
}
```

From my controller I am calling this as,

```
await _fileService.SaveFileContentsAsync(fullPath, httpPostedFileBase.InputStream)
```

My file is saving but with 0 KB. What is the issue here?

Comment: Your action should be Task<ActionResult>, and you must await _fileService.SaveFileContentsAsync(fullPath, httpPostedFileBase.InputStream)

Comment: @Fals returning `Task` is fine; that does not appear to be the action method

Comment: Is the posted code correct?  I don't see a return statement on public async Task SaveFileContentsAsync(string filePath, Stream stream).

Comment: @MobyDisk there doesn't need to be; it is the `async` equivalent of a `void` method.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I found the answer at stream.Position = 0, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349571/stream-copyto-file-empty-asp-net

Comment: @user960567 ah, good catch - I've linked the two questions