# CsvHelper -- attempting to match header in CSV file to expected header, 'no header record was found'

Tags: c#, csv, file-upload, blazor, csvhelper

I have a Blazor Server project where a user will upload a MyFitnessPal CSV file so they can analyse it. I am trying to see if the uploaded CSV file header matches the header that a MyFitnessPal CSV file would have. I have ran into a number of issues in attempting to do this. Here's what the current code looks like:

```
    private async Task LoadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        int randomFileNumber = 1;

        if (e.File.Size < maxFileSize && e.File.ContentType.Equals("text/csv"))
        {
            await using FileStream fs = new($"csv{randomFileNumber:D6}.csv", FileMode.Create);
            await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs);

            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
            {
                Delimiter = ","
            };

            using var reader = new StreamReader(fs);
            using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config);
            string expectedHeaderValues = "Date,Meal,Calories,Fat (g),Saturated Fat,Polyunsaturated Fat,Monounsaturated Fat,Trans Fat,Cholesterol,Sodium (mg),Potassium,Carbohydrates (g),Fiber,Sugar,Protein (g),Vitamin A,Vitamin C,Calcium,Iron,Note";
            await csv.Context.Reader.ReadAsync();
            csv.Context.Reader.ReadHeader();

            csvHeaders = csv.HeaderRecord;

            if (!csvHeaders.Equals(expectedHeaderValues.Split(",")))
            {
                var fileName = fs.Name;
                File.Delete(fileName);
                loadingSuccess = false;
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", $"{e.File.Name} does not have the expected headers, aborting.");
                Logger.LogError("File: {FileName} Error: File does not have the expected headers, aborting.", e.File.Name);
            }
            
            else
            {
                records = csv.GetRecordsAsync<NutritionModel>();
                loadingSuccess = true;
            }
                       
        }
        else
        {
            File.Delete(e.File.Name);
            loadingSuccess = false;
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", $"File: {e.File.Name} Error: File uploaded exceeds maximum limit, or is not a CSV file. Aborting.");
            Logger.LogError("File: {FileName} Error: File uploaded exceeds maximum limit, or is not a CSV file. Aborting.", e.File.Name);
        }
    }
```

So currently my code is trying to read the CSV file and get the header record, but for some reason it doesn't appear to exist when `csv.Context.Reader.ReadHeader()` is called. I'm not sure why as the file is there, the csv file with the new random name is successfully created, so no idea why it would tell that there is no header, as I am trying to upload a MyFitnessPal CSV file that has a header. I have also tried other CSV files with headers and they too end up with the same result.

I am not using a class map, just a standard model with attributes to match the CSV headers to my model fields.

EDIT: Since you requested the runtime error:

```
Exception thrown: 'CsvHelper.ReaderException' in CsvHelper.dll: 'No header record was found.
IReader state:
   ColumnCount: 0
   CurrentIndex: -1
   HeaderRecord:

IParser state:
   ByteCount: 0
   CharCount: 0
   Row: 1
   RawRow: 1
   Count: 0
   RawRecord:'
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.ParseNamedIndexes()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.ReadHeader()
   at islandmonkeyuk.Pages.FileUpload.<LoadFile>d__9.MoveNext() in /home/aidan/vscode/islandmonkeyuk/Pages/FileUpload.razor:line 65
```

And `HeaderRecord` is `string[]?`, it's provided by CsvHelper. `csvRecord` (my code) is also `string[]?`. Not sure if CsvHelper has an equals overload, VS Code does report 1 overload when hovering over the equals function.

Comment: Do you have a run-time error (then post it) or does it just jump to the else branch?

Comment: What type is HeaderRecord and does it have an overload for Equals(string[]) ?

Comment: Added the context that you asked for.

Comment: Well, the either there is no header or it doesn't match. Create a [mre], just 3 columns or so. Test it and when it fails post the code and input here.

Comment: I think you may need to reset the file stream position to the beginning after copying to it.  Try doing `fs.Position = 0;` after `await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs);`.  See e.g. [stream.CopyTo - file empty. asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9349571).

Comment: Also, is the `csv{randomFileNumber:D6}.csv` file intended to be a temp file or a permanently uploaded file?  If a temp file, where do you delete it?  If permanent, is there a chance you are getting some sort of file name collision?

Comment: Did [stream.CopyTo - file empty. asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9349571) answer your question?  If not, then please [edit] your question to share a CSV sample that reproduces your problem.  As it is, absent a CSV sample, we don't have a [mcve] and and so can only guess as to how your question could be answered.  (See also [ask].)

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I will try later on this evening.

Comment: Why not creating a class of a record and let the library parse it for itself. `csv.GetRecords<YourClass>().ToList();`

Comment: @dbc Your first suggestion got things working, fs.Position = 0 meant that the file was now being read properly and I am getting the expected results. Thanks a lot!

Comment: CSV files are just simple text files. Try opening the CSV in Notepad (or some other text editor - not Excel or Word) and confirm whether or not the file has a header line.